# I want to print true if all card have the same suit, and false if not

Tags: python

I want to print true if all cards have the same suit, and false if not, in Python.  It is working good for two arguments:

```
def same_value(card_1, card_2):
    if 'Hearts' in card_1 and 'Hearts' in card_2:
        print('True')
    elif 'Diamonds' in card_1 and 'Diamonds' in card_2:
        print('True')
    elif 'Clubs' in card_1 and 'Clubs' in card_2:
        print('True')
    elif 'Spades' in card_1 and 'Spades' in card_2:
        print('True')
    else:
        print('False')

same_value('2 of Hearts', '3 of Hearts')
```

But it is not working for three or more arguments:

```
def same_value(*cards):
    for card in cards:
        if 'Hearts' in card:
            print('True')
        else:
            print('False')

same_value('2 of Hearts', '3 of Hearts', '4 of Hearts')
```

Comment: You have to check all three cards before printing anything.  This is a well-documented technique.  We need you to finish your research before posting a question here.

Comment: Yes, what exactly do you mean by "it is not working"? Does it cause an error? Does it have the wrong output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g. using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
def same_value(*cards):
    suites = [card.split(' ')[-1] for card in cards]
    unique_suites = len(set(suites))
    print(unique_suites == 1)

same_value('2 of Hearts', '3 of Hearts', 'Ace of Spades')
```

Comment: Upvoted, but while this is a working solution I think Marzymster would benifit more from an explination of why his line of thought is not working than the actual code snippet.

Comment: Thank you Roman for working code and Jekarin for goods advice.

Comment: @marzymster good point, but the problem is not very well specified what are possibilities of input. I just proposed solution to the example input. List comprehension is tricky point so I added the link to the documentation and maybe `len(set(x))` is a trick worth of explaining but I tried to make it clear through the variable names. Feel free to suggest improvement.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick response.

First, your `same_value` only accepts two inputs. Hence it will fail since you pass in three different strings.

I recommend that you change your inputs to a list of strings:

```
def same_value(cards):
```

You can then re-work your call as:
`same_value(['2 of Hearts', '3 of Hearts', '4 of Hearts'])`

I'll follow-up later with a way to improve your if/else logic on how to get the True/False if you have the same suite.